# VB 2013 DownloadFile Error/Exception

Tags: vb.net

Trying to use My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile to fetch a file from an FTP server in VB 2013 Express.  Everything works great when the file is there.  However, I am not able to capture the result when the file is not found.  Using Try-Catch but it never hits the Catch. It brings up an "Unhandled exception has occurred in your application..." error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Try
   My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(server_name, file_name, user_name, password, False, 500, True)
Catch ex As ArgumentException
   MsgBox(ex.GetType().ToString())
Catch ex As TimeoutException
   MsgBox(ex.GetType().ToString()) 'Label1.Text = ex
End Try
```

Comment: Any code would be greatly appreciated

Comment: debug line by line and you'll see exactly where the exception is generated. My guess is that the object returned is null (which doesn't cause exception) but then you try and do something with it, which does.

Comment: The DownloadFile command doesn't return anything, succeed or fail.  The function simply gets the file specified and downloads it to the location specified using the user name and password provided.

Comment: Here's the code: Try
            My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(server_name, file_name, user_name, password, False, 500, True)
        Catch ex As ArgumentException
            MsgBox(ex.GetType().ToString())
        Catch ex As TimeoutException
            MsgBox(ex.GetType().ToString())
            'Label1.Text = ex
        End Try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ack30t8y(v=vs.90).aspx) -- you're not capturing nearly all the possible exception types `DownloadFile` could throw.

```
The following conditions may cause an exception to be thrown:
  The drive name is not valid (ArgumentException).
  destinationFileName ends with a trailing slash (ArgumentException).
  overwrite is set to False and the destination file already exists (IOException).
  The server does not respond within the specified connectionTimeout (TimeoutException).
  The authentication fails (SecurityException).
  User lacks necessary permissions (SecurityException).
  The request is denied by the website (WebException).
```

Try just

```
Try
   My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(server_name, file_name, user_name, password, False, 500, True)
Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.GetType().ToString())
```

to see what is going on.